# How do I open a form in WinForm

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

I am new to WinForm.
I have Visual Studio Express 2015
I have a project with 5 forms.
Form1, Form2, Form3, Form4, Form5.

Form1 opens by default when I start application.
I am working on Form5.

**Question:**
How do I open ONLY Form5 for testing?

I don't want to put a link from Form1 to Form5.
I am not talking about writing some code to open a form.

Answer (score 2):

For **C#**, double click on `program.cs` in the Solution Explorer and change:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

To:

```
Application.Run(new Form5());
```

For **Visual Basic**, click on Project --> Properties and change the `Startup form` dropdown to the Form you want.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Program.cs` file, Replace

```
Application.Run(new Form1);
```

With

```
Application.Run(new Form5);
```

Do the steps in reverse to get it back to normal.

Note: This is in C#